# Flattening Join in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, pivot, crosstab

Is it possible to join a table so that only a specific row at a specific ordered offset is joined instead of every matching record in table?

I have two tables, `Customer` and `MonthlyRecommendation`. `MonthlyRecommendation` points to `Customer` and tracks one product recommendation made by the customer at some day in each month.

I'm trying to write a query that retrieves each customer, along with the last 12-months of recommendations. Simply doing:

```
SELECT c.id, m.date, m.product
FROM Customer AS c
INNER JOIN MonthlyRecommendation AS m ON m.customer_id = c.id
```

will get me the data I want, but I need it flattened so that each customer's data is in one row, and the result signature looks like:

```
id, date_01, product_01, date_02, product_02, ..., date_12, product_12
```

Is there any way to do this in PostgreSQL? For similar problems, I would normally just make 12 separate JOINs, joining on specific sub-condition for each one, but in this case, the condition is relative to the order of the date values in the table. I'd like to be able to specify and ORDER BY, with maybe a LIMIT and OFFSET, but I don't believe and SQL dialect supports that.

Comment: This is called `PIVOT` in SQL Server. See if [this](http://www.craigkerstiens.com/2013/06/27/Pivoting-in-Postgres/) helps in accomplishing this in Postgres.

Comment: See http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tablefunc.html

Answer (score 0):

Some databases support the `pivot` operation directly.  In Postgres, you could use a user-defined function, such as cross tab.  But the aggregation method is simple enough:

```
SELECT c.id,
       '2013-01' as date_01, max(case when m.date = '2013-01' then m.product end) as product_01, 
       '2013-02' as date_02, max(case when m.date = '2013-02' then m.product end) as product_02, 
       . . . 
       '2013-12' as date_12, max(case when m.date = '2013-12' then m.product end) as product_12 
FROM Customer c INNER JOIN
     MonthlyRecommendation m
     ON m.customer_id = c.id
GROUP BY c.id;
```

Of course, the above query is just guessing at a format for `date`.  You'll need to put the right comparison in for your data.